# Tomcat 9.0.12 and mySQL (8.0.12) with springBoot (I guess)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, tomcat

I know the problem looks pretty old, but I shall apreciate any suggestion.
Because a hosting server accept only Tomcat 8, I changed a project which worked fine with Tomee Plume: made also some changes to Tomcat 8.5 (put some jar, e.g. catalina-ws, jaxrpc-1.4.0, wsdl4j.wso2-1.6.3.wso2v3),

Now, apparently weird, no project and neither Tocat 9 run with mySQL.

The pom file:

```xml
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>        
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.9</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
```

```java
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "ro.prj.mysqlsboot.model") 
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ro.prj.mysqlsboot.model")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "ro.prj.mysqlsboot.controller")
    public class MysqlSbootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(MysqlSbootApplication.class, args);

        }

    }


    @Repository
    @Component
    public interface CondRepository extends JpaRepository<Cond, Integer>{
    }

    @Service
    @RestController
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "ro.rodit.mysqlsboot.model")
    public class Controller {

        @Autowired
        CondRepository condRepo;

        @GetMapping({"/login", ""})
        public String getView() {
            return "index";
        }

        @GetMapping("/gd")
        @ResponseBody
        public ModelAndView getId(@RequestParam Integer id) {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
            Cond cd = condRepo.findById(id).orElse(new Cond());
            mv.addObject(cd);
            return mv;
        }
     }
```

The Entity class:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Cond {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        private Integer id;

        //the other parameters, incl. getter & setters ...
    }
```

Some tomcat message:

```
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:08.045 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\TomeePlume\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.0-M1\conf\Catalina\localhost\mavenMobils.xml] has finished in [8,748] ms
    Hibernate: 
        select
            cond0_.id as id1_0_0_,
            cond0_.ecran as ecran2_0_0_,
            cond0_.fcorectie_aer_liber as fcorecti3_0_0_,
            cond0_.fcorectie_f1 as fcorecti4_0_0_,
            cond0_.fcorectie_f2 as fcorecti5_0_0_,
            cond0_.gradul_de_incarcare as gradul_d6_0_0_,
            cond0_.i_adm as i_adm7_0_0_,
            cond0_.i_adm_efg as i_adm_ef8_0_0_,
            cond0_.izolatie as izolatie9_0_0_,
            cond0_.k1 as k10_0_0_,
            cond0_.k2 as k11_0_0_,
            cond0_.manta as manta12_0_0_,
            cond0_.material_cu_al as materia13_0_0_,
            cond0_.mod_pozare55 as mod_poz14_0_0_,
            cond0_.nr_cond_incarcate as nr_cond15_0_0_,
            cond0_.rezist_termica_sol as rezist_16_0_0_,
            cond0_.sectiunen as sectiun17_0_0_,
            cond0_.temp_ambianta_de_referinta as temp_am18_0_0_,
            cond0_.temp_funct_adm as temp_fu19_0_0_,
            cond0_.temp_solului as temp_so20_0_0_,
            cond0_.tensiune as tensiun21_0_0_ 
        from
            cond cond0_ 
        where
            cond0_.id=?
    2020-01-13 12:09:16.153 TRACE 4064 --- [io-8080-exec-47] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [11]
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.052 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\TomeePlume\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.0-M1\conf\Catalina\localhost\account.xml]
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.053 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke The path attribute with value [/account] in deployment descriptor [C:\TomeePlume\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.0-M1\conf\Catalina\localhost\account.xml] has been ignored
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.054 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /account
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.197 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Creation of the naming context failed: [javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only]
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.568 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: D:\NBean\Projects\Spring\gihub\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\target\account-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.738 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/TestDB, type=Resource, provider-id=ProvidedByTomcat)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.740 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/pol, type=Resource, provider-id=ProvidedByTomcat)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.740 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/TestDB)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.745 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/pol)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.748 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/TestDB' in bean account.Comp380682656 to Resource(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/TestDB)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.748 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/jdbc/TestDB' in bean account.Comp380682656 to Resource(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/TestDB)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.748 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/pol' in bean account.Comp380682656 to Resource(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/pol)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.749 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/jdbc/pol' in bean account.Comp380682656 to Resource(id=account-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc/pol)
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.782 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "D:\NBean\Projects\Spring\gihub\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\target\account-1.0-SNAPSHOT" loaded.
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:18.783 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: D:\NBean\Projects\Spring\gihub\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\target\account-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    12:09:19.026 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
    12:09:19.113 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.1.Final
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:19.115 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: D:\NBean\Projects\Spring\gihub\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql-master\target\account-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    13-Jan-2020 12:09:19.115 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component
StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/account]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
```

Comment: I used "private final CondRepository condRepo" instead of @Autowired and it still does not work: so it is about jpa

Comment: It looks to be a jpa-spring boot matter. I know this is not a blog, but I must say that Spring boot is supposed to be a fast & easy tool, but not a source of unclear problems. Until get it, I continue with spring mvc which goes very well! However, I am still waiting for any help & suggestion! Thanks!